# Why does Tomcat start with 0.0.0.0:8000 open?

Tags: debugging, tomcat, ubuntu-10.10, jpda

I know the short answer is "You told it to." But of course, I'm not sure how I told Tomcat to start with the `8000` default debug port open, but on `0.0.0.0` instead of the expected `127.0.0.1`. Here's a couple of context commands directly after Ubuntu 10.10 boots.

```
$ netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN     

/usr/share/tomcat6/bin$ grep -C 5 8000 catalina.sh
#
#   JPDA_TRANSPORT  (Optional) JPDA transport used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is "dt_socket".
#
#   JPDA_ADDRESS    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. The default is 8000.
#
#   JPDA_SUSPEND    (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "jpda start"
#                   command is executed. Specifies whether JVM should suspend
#                   execution immediately after startup. Default is "n".
#
--
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
```

Given these two outputs, I expect to find out that there's a further configuration file somewhere that I unknowingly modified, since the only way that `catalina.sh` would open `8000` is if it was passed the `jpda` switch, and even then it seems like it will start on `localhost` and no `0.0.0.0`. `.bashrc` is clean of tomcat tomfoolery, and I'm stumped where else to look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to brush up on [RFC4632](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632), memory got rusty.

0.0.0.0 is the [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route), and in the case of Tomcat is used to indicate that *any* IP on port `8000` will be routed into Tomcat (presumably for debugging).

To restate, on Tomcat `0.0.0.0:xxxx` will route any request with `xxxx` port into Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

That could be becuase the JPDA_ADDRESS is "8000" and not "localhost:8000"
if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:8000"
 fi